# Terminology for groupings/categories within ArcGIS Pro galleries?

Tags: arcgis-pro, terminology

In ArcGIS Pro 1.1.1, when I use the INSERT tab to insert a New Layout, I am offered a gallery of layout templates to choose from.

I think the terminology that I have used so far matches that found in ArcGIS Pro's [Terminology and user interface reference guide](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/get-started/arcgis-pro-terminology.htm).

I then, for example, want to choose the **A3** template from the **ISO - Portrait** category.

[image]

Is the term **category** the correct one to apply here?

The [Terminology and user interface reference guide](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/get-started/arcgis-pro-terminology.htm) does not seem to mention what term should be used to refer to any groupings within galleries.

Comment: Yes, I think I would call it a **category** or maybe a **set**, although I'm not sure if there's a proper term for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to write documentation describing this heading would be, "Under **Iso-Portrait**, click the A3 template."